# How to use query to differentiate whether a field doesn't exist or it exists but its value is an empty array?

Tags: elasticsearch

What I want to achieve is that:

1. When a field doesn't exist, this document should be returned.
2. When a field exists but its value is an empty array, this document should NOT be returned.

It seems that I cannot use exists query because it doesn't differentiate the two cases.

Should I use something like below?

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "weekly_hours.monday_hours"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['weekly_hours.monday_hours'].size != 0",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way, both the situations mentioned above will return `true` in the `must_not` section, then in the `filter` the 2nd situation will be filtered out as its size is 0.

Is that correct?

Is there any simpler way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

I tried the script mentioned above. I guess the idea works but an exception `Fielddata is not supported on field [weekly_hours.monday_hours] of type [date_range]` occurred, as shown below.

```
{
    "took": 12,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 4,
        "failed": 1,
        "failures": [
            {
                "shard": 3,
                "index": "items",
                "node": "jRtjvF1mTzG_jPTqkDo2uA",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "script_exception",
                    "reason": "runtime error",
                    "script_stack": [
                        "org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MappedFieldType.fielddataBuilder(MappedFieldType.java:103)",
                        "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexFieldDataService.getForField(IndexFieldDataService.java:111)",
                        "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$1.run(LeafDocLookup.java:87)",
                        "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$1.run(LeafDocLookup.java:84)",
                        "java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)",
                        "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:84)",
                        "doc['weekly_hours.monday_hours'].size() != 0",
                        "    ^---- HERE"
                    ],
                    "script": "doc['weekly_hours.monday_hours'].size() != 0",
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                        "reason": "Fielddata is not supported on field [weekly_hours.monday_hours] of type [date_range]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

The `monday_hours` field is of type `date_range`.
Does that mean I cannot use script on this field at all?
If so, how to achieve the effect I described at the beginning of the question?
Really need help here...

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `must_not` on `weekly_hours.monday_hours` would *technically* filter out all the missing docs so calling `doc['weekly_hours.monday_hours'].size() != 0` wouldn't have any further effect. I said `technically` because ES does not treat all missing values the same -- I'll elaborate below.

What's worse is that `date_range` fields currently (>=7.9) [don't support the `null_value` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html) which is already possible in other field types and [makes one's life easier](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html) in situations like these.

I tested a few variations of emptyish fields:

```
1.
{
  "weekly_hours":{
    
  }
}

2.
{
  "weekly_hours":{
    "monday_hours":{
      
    }
  }
}

3.
{
 "weekly_hours":{
    "monday_hours":{
      "gte":null,
      "lte":null
    }
  }
}
```

and finally a valid one

```
{
  "weekly_hours":{
    "monday_hours":{
      "gte":"2015-10-31 12:00:00",
      "lte":"2015-11-01"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I'd *expect* the following query to return only `4.` but it does not and I think it's worth [filing a bug report](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/new/choose):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "weekly_hours.monday_hours"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "weekly_hours.monday_hours": {
              "gte": "1970-01-01",
              "lte": "2999-12-31"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "_exists_:weekly_hours AND _exists_:weekly_hours.monday_hours AND weekly_hours.monday_hours:[1970-01-01 TO 2999-12-31] AND NOT weekly_hours.monday_hours:[null TO null]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

One final remark: wouldn't it be simpler to use `integer_ranges` instead of `date_ranges` for day-of-week hours? Now, given that all these ranges belong to the same field type family, I'd go ditch them for now and follow [this neat opening hours approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7118625/8160318).

Comment: The effect I want to achieve is that "When a field does NOT exist, this document SHOULD be returned." So I think the `must_not` + `exists` part should be fine, is that right? And, I am afraid I cannot change the `date_ranges` type now. In fact, if `"source": "doc['weekly_hours.monday_hours'].size != 0"` works, the problem will be solved, right? But why there is that `Fielddata is not supported on field [weekly_hours.monday_hours] of type [date_range]` error?

Comment: My question are: 1. whether that means I canNOT use script on `date_ranges` type? 2. Is there any other way to check if a field is empty other than using script? Thank you so much!

Comment: 1. scripting on date_ranges does not bring anything b/c you cannot access the field values (at least not yet -- maybe possible in the future). 2. not easily, as outlined above, so it's worth filing a bug report with the elastic team...